# Heroku permission denied for database "postgres"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

For 2 hours now, i have been trying to get mailer working in heroku.

I am using ruby on rails and my code worked fine until i tried to setup mailer with gmail per [this](http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/handling-emails-in-rails) guide.

i have added these lines to my /config/environments/production.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'gigitt.herokuapp.com' }
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'gigitt.herokuapp.com'
```

Everything pushes to heroku fine but when i try to: heroku run rake db:setup 
I get the following error:

```
Running `rake db:setup` attached to terminal... up, run.9482
FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:567:in `retrieve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:8:in `connection'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb:17:in `create'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:93:in `create'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:107:in `block in create_current'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:275:in `block in each_current_configuration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:274:in `each_current_configuration'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:106:in `create_current'
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:17:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:201:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `each'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:178:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/app/vendor/ruby-2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/app/bin/rake:4:in `<main>'
Couldn't create database for {"adapter"=>"postgresql",
```

Once i remove those lines, i get this error:

```
2015-04-30T21:15:21.935684+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionView::Template::Error (Missing host to link to! Please provide the :host parameter, set default_url_options[:host], or set :only_path to true):
```

So i need the lines but it wont work with it, any ideas?

Comment: try pg:setup instead of db

Comment: Don't know how to build task 'pg:setup' is the error i get

Comment: Why are you running db:setup?  Heroku doesn't let you create databases like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, well i got it working.  here is my production.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://gigitt.herokuapp.com' }
  Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'http://gigitt.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # SMTP settings for gmail
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
   address:               "smtp.gmail.com",
   port:                  587,
   domain:                ENV["GMAIL_DOMAIN"],
   authentication:        "plain",
   enable_starttls_auto:  true,
   user_name:             ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
   password:              ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD']
  }
end
```

my .env:

```
GMAIL_DOMAIN=mail.website.com.com
GMAIL_USERNAME=email@website.com
GMAIL_PASSWORD=password
```

i pushed the commit to heroku, did not run heroku run rake db:setup instead just ran heroku run rake db:migrate.  now it is all working :-D

Answer (score 9):

`rake db:setup` attempts to create the database, you can't do that on Heroku using rake.  Do you have a pg database created?  You said your code worked fine until the mailer, so I'm guessing you do.  If you want to run migrations, just run `rake db:migrate`.

Comment: yes, the db is running fine.  i just cant seem to get the app to work for email recovery, that is what seems to break it.

Comment: Right, but why are you running db:setup?  What told you to do that and what does that have to do w/email?

Comment: nothing told me, i had just done it before and never had an issue with it.  i have even created a new app and did not run db:setup and had no luck

Comment: It will work locally but not on heroku. Do you have migrations?  If not have you tried your email changes?  This doesn't seem like a problem.